# "WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to String" Exception in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When writing in Spark Java I'm meeting this error while accessing a column of row of a Dataframe. I don't get why `WrappedArray` is retrieved from the Row instead of a normal Array.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.String
```

Example code :
String[] myarray = my_df_row.getAs("col_name");

I need Java code, not scala or python.
How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The WrappedArray needs to be converted to a Java list and then an Array. Code example :

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;

String[] myarray;
myarray = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(my_df_row.getAs("col_name")).toArray(myarray);
```